# Can I use plural nouns in table headings?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

I've always thought that table headings need to be singular. However, I've come across examples when that hasn't been the case.

For example, if there is a table that shows the number of visits that each store had in a year from all over the country, the heading (the first column) that lists stores would be "Store," but the heading (the second column) that lists the number of visits would be "Visits" instead of "Visit."

What would be the rule to follow?

Comment: Very good question. I too always wondered this! +1

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it seems clear. Because the column is telling about **one store** and its **visits** (of customers). Let's take that as an example:

> *"How many **visits** of customers do you notice in a year for **this** store?"*

**over...**

> *"There was just **one** visit in a year for this store."*

Since the rows of **visit** column is likely to have more than *one* visit, it is labeled as **visits**. On the other hand, the first column's all rows will have only *one* store and thus it has the heading of *store*.

In most of such cases, we need to think what exactly the ***row*** will define. For instance, a table on the very first page of a textbook may contain

> Index (the lesson number - singular) 
>  Lesson (the title of ONE lesson - singular) 
>   Page number (one page number of that lesson - singular).

On the other hand, we will have heading in plural in some cases where the ***row*** reflects plural matter.

Say we are having ***a price list*** of some items.

[image]

Here, the second column takes *Item* as a **singular** because, I'm defining ***one item*** per row.

Now we have ***a grade list*** of furniture

[image]

Certainly, the second column shall have the word *Items* plural because each row is defining the items that are more than one.

Comment: Looking at each row... Got it. It seems pretty clear looking at it that way :)