# "Task names" or "tasks names"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

If I am looking at a list of tasks and I want to say "names of the tasks", is it wrong to say "task**s** names" ? I usually see "task names", but how do you know that that means "the names of the task**s**" instead of "the names of the task" (a task can have more names) ?

The choice of "task" and "name" here is just an example, it could be anything.

Comment: If you go 'row-by-row', you can use that - 'task name'. If you are going by a column, it becomes 'tasks' names' (note the apostrophe, however, it's not mandatory as we are talking about the heading of the column. We take liberty there!).

Comment: As a plural compound noun, I would definitely say "task names". "Tasks' names" sounds clunky and awkward. (The exception would be if, for example, we were criticising the names of the tasks: "The tasks' names are not very intuitive.")

Comment: @MaulikV I want to say "names of the task**s**" so in your metaphor it would mean that I'm going by a column.

Comment: @JMB Yes, that's what I usually see, "task names", but does that mean that we are giving up the ability to tell whether we mean "the names of the task**s**" or "the names of the task" ?

BTW, why would it make a difference if we were criticizing the names ? Is there something special about criticizing ? This sounds like something new and very interesting for me to learn.

Comment: No, it'd be 'name' of the task then... raw includes singular thing, column includes more than one, doesn't it?

Comment: My answer on the similar question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33857/can-i-use-plural-nouns-in-table-headings/33859#33859

Comment: @MaulikV If it is "name of the task" it means one task, while I'm talking about several task**s**. Like in _The names of the tasks are all very strange._

Comment: check the link I gave

Comment: @MaulikV I checked your other answer but I am still unclear. Forget about my reference to a list. I want to say "names of the tasks" and my question was whether that translates to "task**s** names" or "task names".

Comment: it says 'tasks' name'. Name of the friends I have....it represents 'Friends' Names'...doesn't it? To make it simple, forget 'task' replace it with any noun. What do you think now?

Comment: @MaulikV It's difficult for me to follow you, I will try again later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

English does not require that modifiers agree in plurality with nouns like some other languages.

In the phrase *task names* - *task* is an adjective answering the question *what kind?* for the noun *names*.  The *s* on the end of task would only be present if it's a plural noun (or singular verb - e.g. *she tasks me with taking out the trash.*).

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies my doubt, it's _task names_ no matter it's one task or several tasks. So - if I understood correctly - if in some specific situation I need to make it absolutely clear that it's more than one task I will just say _The names of the tasks_.